# Insert numbers divisible by a number into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I was given the integers 15, 16, 17 ,18 ,19 and 20.

I am supposed to put only the numbers divisible by 4 into a vector and then display the values in the vector.

I know how to do the problem using arrays but I'm guessing I don't know how to properly use pushback or vectors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<int> arrmain; int i,j;

for (int i = 15; i <=20 ; i++)
{
        //checking which numbers are divisible by 4
    if (i%4 == 0)
    {   //if number is divisible by 4 inserting them into arrmain 

        arrmain.push_back(i);
        //output the elements in the vector
        for(j=0; j<=arrmain.size(); j++)
        {
            cout <<arrmain[i]<< " "<<endl;
        }
    }
 }

return 0;
 }
```

wanted output: Numbers divisible by 4: 16, 20

Comment: Your code looks a bit inconsistent and your {} ain't all at the right place, though, passed that the solution looks good except for the out-of-bounds indexing since you are using the wrong variable as index. I do recommend using more modern structures, like the range-based for-loop, as it makes your code less error-prone.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'm not familiar with range based for loops. What do you mean by out of bound indexing? Thank you.

Comment: I've added an answer where I explain it in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, I found two bugs which are fixed in code below.

```
vector<int> arrmain; int i, j;

    for (int i = 15; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        //checking which numbers are divisible by 4
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {   //if number is divisible by 4 inserting them into arrmain 

            arrmain.push_back(i);
            //output the elements in the vector
            for (j = 0; j < arrmain.size(); j++)   // should be < instead of <=
            {
                cout << arrmain[j] << " " << endl;    // j instead of i
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will output: 16 16 20, as you are printing elements of vector after each insert operation. You can take second loop outside to avoid doing repeated operations.

Basically, vectors are used in case of handling dynamic size change. So you can use push_back() if you want to increase the size of the vector dynamically or you can use []operator if size is already predefined.

Comment: My error was in approaching it like i would an array. Thank you i understand how my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The main issues in your code are that you are (1) using the wrong variable to index your vector when printing its values, i.e. you use `cout <<arrmain[i]` instead of `cout <<arrmain[j]`; and (2) that you exceed array bounds when iterating up to `j <= arrmain.size()` (instead of `j < arrmain.size()`. Note that `arrmain[arrmain.size()]` exceeds the vector's bounds by one because vector indices are 0-based; an vector of size 5, for example, has valid indices ranging from `0..4`, and `5` is out of bounds.

A minor issue is that you print the array's contents again and again while filling it up. You probably want to print it once after the first loop, not again and again within it.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> arrmain;

    for (int i = 15; i <=20 ; i++)
    {
        //checking which numbers are divisible by 4
        if (i%4 == 0)
        {   //if number is divisible by 4 inserting them into arrmain

            arrmain.push_back(i);
                    }
    }
    //output the elements in the vector
    for(int j=0; j<arrmain.size(); j++)
    {
        cout <<arrmain[j]<< " "<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Concerning the range-based for loop mentioned in the comment, note that you can iterate over the elements of a vector using the following abbreviate syntax:

```
// could also be written as range-based for loop:
for(auto val : arrmain) {
    cout << val << " "<<endl;
}
```

This syntax is called a **range-based for loop** and is described, for example, [here at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: I didn't even know range- based for loops existed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you have a couple of problems in your code.
All which will bite you in the end when writing more code.
A lot of them can be told to you by compiler-tools. For example by using [`-Weverything` in clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YmqxmQ).

To pick out the most important ones:

> source.cpp:8:10: warning: declaration shadows a local variable [-Wshadow]
>
> for (int i = 15; i <=20 ; i++)

and

> source.cpp:6:26: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
>
> vector arrmain; int i,j;

Beside those, you have a logical issue in your code:

```
for values to check
    if value is ok
        print all known correct values
```

This will result in: 16, 16, 20 when ran.
Instead, you want to change the scope of the printing so it doesn't print on every match.

Finally, the bug you are seeing:

```
for(j=0; j<=arrmain.size(); j++)
{
    cout <<arrmain[i]<< " "<<endl;
}
```

This bug is the result of poor naming, let me rename so you see the problem:

```
for(innercounter=0; innercounter<=arrmain.size(); innercounter++)
{
    cout <<arrmain[outercounter]<< " "<<endl;
}
```

Now, it should be clear that you are using the wrong variable to index the vector. This will be indexes 16 and 20, in a vector with max size of 2. As these indexes are out-of-bounds for the vector, you have undefined behavior. When using the right index, the `<=` also causes you to go 1 index out of the bounds of the vector use `<` instead.

Besides using better names for your variables, I would recommend using the range based for. This is available since C++11.

```
for (int value : arrmain)
{
    cout << value << " "<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the compiler tool! It will be very handy!